# Rspec testing specific nodes in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'd like to isolate specific nodes to test on.

e.g. instead of

```
get :show
response.should have_content(@user.name)
```

it would be more descriptive/correct to be able to write something like

```
get :show
profile = response.find_selector("div.user-profile")
profile.should have_content(@user.name)
```

is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Got a bit further with this after reading Peter's answer but still not finding elements.

in `app\views\users\index.html.erb`

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<div id="test"></div>
```

in `spec\controllers\users_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  render_views

  it "should should have header" do
    get :index
    response.should have_selector("h1", content: "Users")        
  end

  it "should show user profile" do
    get :index
    node = page.find_by_id("test")
    p node
  end

end
```

The first test passes, the second test gives `ElementNotFound` error. I'm possibly just doing something stupid as this is my first go at Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Capybara doesn't have `find_selector`, but it does have `find` and derivatives which take a `locator` and behave as you imply above.  See http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders

For example, instead of:

```
page.should have_selector('foo', text: 'bar')
```

you can say:

```
node = page.find('foo')
node.should have_content('bar')
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I can't get it working, could you give an example please? `get :index; Capybara::Node::Simple.new(response.body).find("#test");` This isn't finding the element. I'm new to Ruby so maybe reading the docs wrong.

Comment: See the updated answer for an example which I just tested with one of my existing tests.  As to why the code snippet you gave didn't work, I would need to see more. Did you try just modifying the example you gave in your question?

Comment: See http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/. I still don't understand this fully, but you need to use `response` with `get` and `page` with `visit`. You've used `get` with `page` in your second example.